# Showing different markers on different points in react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a react native app where i'm using `react-native-maps`.Here, i want to show different marker images for different points according to their coordinate indexes. But its showing just one same marker for all. Here is the code i have now:

```js
 {this.state.coordinates.map((coordinate, index) =>
              <MapView.Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} 
                              coordinate={coordinate} 
                              title={coordinate.title} 
                              description={coordinate.description} 
                              image={require(../assests/1.png)}>
             </MapView.Marker>
            )}
```

I have more images named 2.png , 3.png etc. How can i show these images in different coordinates such as for index 0 ,it will get 1.png. For index 1,it will get 2.png. What is the wayout from here?

Answer (score 0):

You are hard coding image index to `1`, this code should work:

```
{this.state.coordinates.map((coordinate, index) =>
              <MapView.Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} 
                              coordinate={coordinate} 
                              title={coordinate.title} 
                              description={coordinate.description} 
                              image={require(`../assests/${index}.png`)}>
             </MapView.Marker>
            )}
```

Comment: This throws an error like invalid call at line - require(`../assests/${index}.png`) @Taym

Comment: `index` started from `0` you probably don't have image `0.png`!

Comment: error: bundling failed: Error: src\screens\JobDetailsScreen.js:Invalid call at line 119: require("../assests/" + index + ".png") This is the exact error and i do have 0.png. So, where is the problem?

Comment: use this : require("../assests/" + index.toString() + ".png")

Comment: Still showing this : error: bundling failed: Error: src\screens\JobDetailsScreen.js:Invalid call at line 119: require("../assests/" + index.toString() + ".png")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196610/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarker-and-taym).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I hope it solved your problem.

First form the marker array.
For Ex.

```
var marker1 = {
    coordinates: {
                latitude: ...,
                longitude: ...
            },
            key: MARKER1,
            image: require(../assests/1.png)
        };

var marker2 = {
            coordinates: {
                latitude: ...,
                longitude: ...
            },
            key: MARKER2,
            image: require(../assests/2.png)
        };
```

//Push it into your marker array

```
this.state.markers.push(marker1);
this.state.markers.push(marker2);
```

//Render

```
<MapView
...
{this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                            <MapView.Marker
                                coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                                key={marker.key}>
                                <Image source={marker.image} style={width:50, height:50}/>
                            </MapView.Marker>
                        ))}
</MapView>
```

Comment: Still problem on <Image source={marker.image} style={width:50, height:50}/>

Comment: can you please share me what is the exact problem for you? are you able to render marker in maps or some error?

Comment: I am able to render marker. But when it maps and supposed to show different markers on different position which is not happening.

Comment: How you are generating the marker array? can you please share example

Comment: Here's the complete code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3fk4bo?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Try this. Use require while form the array.      coordinates.map((coord) => {
          var imageURL = String(coord.image);
          const coordsNumber = {
            'latitude': Number(coord.latitude),
            'longitude': Number(coord.longitude),
            'title': String(coord.title),
            'description': String(coord.description),
            'image': require(imageURL)
          }
          geoCoordinates.push(coordsNumber)

        }